# Textinput (React Native - Android) - Support onKeyPreIme

Tags: android, react-native

In native code (java) I can create `TextInput` with handle `onKeyPreIme`

Like this

> ```
> com/myapp/CustomEditText.java
> ```

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

  public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

> xml

```
// res/layout/activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myapp.CustomEditText
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/someid"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
/>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
// com/myapp/MainActivity.java

package com.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
...
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //this line test TextInput
    ...  
  }
}
```

Does react native support to do this in `TextInput` ?

Thank for any help.

Edit : My goal is stop back press while keyboard shown.
In native is easy with `onKeyPreIme`.
I try with `@Override onBackPress` and `BackHandler` of React native but does not work, too.

```
// MainActivity.java

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  return;
}
```

This code not work while keyboard shown.

Comment: You can easily do it with `BackHandler` and `Keyboard` component of react-native. Just check is keyboard or shown or not then handle it in BackHandler.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg How to use BackHandler for force keyboard do not hide while keyboard shown in android ? I already try but keyboard still hide. I test by add `console.log` to `BackHandler` but console not show anything on press Back while keyboard shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const blackBack = () => true;

Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
    BackHandler.addListener('hardwareBackPress', blackBack)
});

Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
    BackHandler.removeListener('hardwareBackPress', blackBack)
});
```

Comment: Oh maybe this doesnt catch `onPreIme`. That's interesting

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the callback is not getting called